# Length of space/blank character (" ") in Excel formula

Tags: excel

I have the following formula which I designed to align text strings of different length around their dot sign in an Excel table column:
REPT(" ",4-FIND(".",A1))&A1

My problem is that the first character of the source string is often the minus sign "-". Thus, as the length of the minus sign is a bit shorter than the length of the blank space sign that REPT function produces, I am left with a not really perfect alignment.

Is there a way that I adjust my formula so that it repeats the necessary blank space signs with a length equal to the length of the minus sign?

Comment: Sounds like you are struggling to used fixed alignment with a variable width font.  Why not just use a fixed-width font formatting for the cell(s)?  Then it won't matter which character you use to "align."  If this is purely meant to be visual, it may make more sense to split the content into two cells (whereby the cell border becomes the alignment element).

Comment: @D.N. Unfortunately I should use Arial. Maybe I did not understand your last sentence - but I also need the content in one cell in the end. Maybe your solution is to first separate the minus sign, then make the alignment and only then add back the minus sign? I guess this could work. I hoped for a simpler way though. For example in Excel custom formats I have seen a format such as "_-0.0;-0.0" which aligns negative and positive numbers by putting such a space before the positive ones which is of the length of the minus sign, so I hoped for a similar solution.

Comment: Are the strings purely numerical, or do you have to do this for alphanumeric?  If purely numerical, use a custom format string of `0.???` (use another `?` for each decimal point you wish to display).

Comment: They are numbers but many of them have a letter flag in the end so they are thus practically alphanumerical.

Comment: I strongly suggest you show some sample data to get a better sense of what we're dealing with.  However, keep in mind that using Excel for "advanced" formatting is not the best option.  Your best bet is still to split the data into separate cells for display purposes - all other calculation needs can be handled by the original cell, which can be hidden if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In Arial, the length of the minus sign seems to be equal to that of the Three-Per-Em Space. Adjust your formula so that it will insert this different length space when required. To insert this space in your formula, create your formula as normal with an empty pair of double-quotes ready to hold this space symbol.

In a different cell, select "Symbol" from the "Insert" tab. Select the Arial Font and the General Punctuation Subset. Find the Three-Per-Em Space and click Insert.

Double click into that cell and copy the special space character. Then go back to your formula and paste it in.

[image]

Comment: No worries, can you please mark my answer as correct using the tick/vote buttons. Thanks.